# Tera Termのログファイル名に変数を入れたい

Tags: teraterm

Tera termの　logopen logname 0 1というコマンドを使って,
マクロの中でログを取得しています。
現在、ホスト名と日付を入れたログファイルを作成するのに
YYYYMMDD_myhost_HHMMSS.log としたいので

gettime adddate "%Y%m%d_"
gettime addtime "_%H%M%S.log"

logname = adddate
strconcat logname myhost
strconcat logname addtime

logopen logname 0 1

としています。myhostの部分が変数であったり、定数であったりするので
文字列としてつなげる方法はstrconcatしかないと思っているのですが
もう少し短く綺麗に書く方法はないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のように [sprintf2](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/ja/macro/command/sprintf2.html) を使うのはどうでしょうか

```
getdate date "%Y%m%d"
gettime time "%H%M%S"

sprintf2 logname "%s_%s_%s.log" date myhost time

logopen logname 0 1
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！すっきりしていい感じです！